# CCMotionStreak straight lines

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I like the effect of CCMotionStreak and Im looking at it to replace a draw function.
But can you do a straight line with it rather than follow the path of the touch? If so how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

see this bellow link , may you got some idea from this Tutorial ..

http://www.merowing.info/2012/04/drawing-smooth-lines-with-cocos2d-ios-inspired-by-paper/

also see this..

1. http://www.supersuraccoon-cocos2d.com/2011/11/03/ensimple-line-follow-demo-ccmotionstreakzh-ccmotionstreakja-ccmotionstreak/
2. http://www.scribd.com/doc/101213799/30/CCMotionStreak

Comment: I have read through this before but I was really looking to use CCMotionStrek for the fade and other functionality.